# Can't save String to SharedPreference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using this to write some String to shared preference.

```
    SharedPreferences urls = getSharedPreferences("imagesRemoteUrls", 0);
     editorUrls = urls.edit();

 editorUrls.putString("url3", imageUrl3);
```

And i try to pull the url out by.

```
 imageUrl3 = urls.getString("url3","nothing");
```

I dont know why but it returns "nothing" each time. Even when i log that the url has been put in the preference successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget:

```
editorUrls.commit();
```

after your `editorUrls.putString()` line!

Comment: Simple error to make I'm sure we've all made something similar, I know I have.